# javascript library installation vs. just copying .js files

Tags: javascript

I'm just learning web development and javascript.  On many open-source javascript libraries, such as jqueryUI, the accompanying readme file contains installation instructions.  The instructions often call for other packages such as node, grunt, npm, etc. to be installed first before the target-library installation can be run.  I'm confused as to why I need to do an installation at all.

What's the difference between just copying the appropriate .js file/files from the target libarary to include in the a script tag, and going through an installation?

Comment: I think you're looking at installation instructions for developers, i.e. people who make jQuery UI itself. If you just want to use it you don't need any of that stuff.

Comment: Installation can ensure latest packages. npm utilities can help you compose js into minified files, image directories into spritesheets, etc. Not necessary but it can help if you care to go through the hassle

Comment: Juhana, thanks for your reply.

When I go into jqueryUI.com, there's a download button for the stable version.  When I clicked that, a whole bunch of stuff came in a .zip file.  Since I only want to use JqueryUI in my own code, and not do any development relating to jqueryUI itself, do I just go through the installed files and just pick out the appropriate .js files to include in my script tag?

Comment: Yes. [Read the documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/).

Comment: For whatever it's worth, many times a better practice than having a copy of a popular library in your js directory is to reference a commonly-used script hosting site in your HTML files. For the most popular one, see this page: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Answer (score 0):

Some javascript libraries build upon other libraries. These libraries must also be included for them to work. jQueryUI depends on jQuery. It doesn't depend on the other libraries you listed. You won't have to copy these.

All you need to use jQueryUI are the two files [jquery-1.10.2.min.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js) and [jquery-ui.js](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js). Put them into the same directory where your html files are, and add these lines between `<head>` and `</head>` of the HTML files which use them:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: So if I go through installation, I'll get all the .js files I need in one place for including in my scripts.  I don't know anything node.js, npm, grunt, or any of the other packages mentioned, and was wondering whether I have to spent time learning those.